# Is there a save draft feature when asking a question?

Tags: feature-request

I may be mistaken, but last time I tried to ask a question, I was unable to finish it so I had to discard it, so does anyone know if there is a save draft feature?

Comment: This is of interest: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/allow-questions-to-be-saved-as-drafts-prior-to-posting/66238#66238

Comment: However, I will say that the best save method I have found is a text file on your computer. :)

Comment: If you *do not* discard draft but simply navigate away from the page (on which a draft was saved), you should see it when visiting the question again.

Comment: [Manual Draft Save - Save a draft on demand](http://stackapps.com/q/2086/14829)